# ¿Como cambiar fuente de impresora EPSON LX-300+II desde C#?

Tags: c#, .net, impresión

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación que pueda imprimir tickets de venta a una impresora con el modelo mencionado en el título. Descargué una clase llamada CrearTicket.cs que encontré en algún foro hace algunas semanas. Esta clase funciona muy bien y es fácil de usar, pero el problema es que al mandar a imprimir el texto este sale con la fuente "Draft" pero es muy gruesa, busco que se imprima con la fuente "Draft Condensed".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtuve este manual desde la página oficial de epson e indica que esos son los comandos ESC/P para cambiar de fuente pero no estoy seguro de como semanden estos comandos a través de esta clase CrearTicket.cs.
Lo que he intentado es enviar algunos comando de la siguiente manera:`linea.AppendLine("\x1bx"); //(ESC x)` al principio de la cadena pero jamás vi un cambio en la fuente.

Adjunto clase CrearTicket.cs.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TicketVenta
{
    class CrearTicket
    {
        StringBuilder linea = new StringBuilder();
        private Image headerImage = null;
        //Creamos una variable para almacenar el numero maximo de caracteres que permitiremos en el ticket.
        int maxCar = 48, cortar;//Para una impresora ticketera que imprime a 40 columnas. La variable cortar cortara el texto cuando rebase el limte.

        public Image HeaderImage
        {
            get { return headerImage; }
            set { if (headerImage != value) headerImage = value; }
        }

        //Creamos el primer metodo, este dibujara lineas guion.
        public string lineasGuio()
        {
            string lineasGuion = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxCar; i++)        
            {
                lineasGuion += "-";//Agregara un guio hasta llegar la numero maximo de caracteres.
            }
            return linea.AppendLine(lineasGuion).ToString(); //Devolvemos la lineaGuion
        }

        //Metodo para dibujar una linea con asteriscos
        public string lineasAsteriscos()
        {
            string lineasAsterisco = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxCar; i++)
            {
                lineasAsterisco += "*";//Agregara un asterisco hasta llegar la numero maximo de caracteres.
            }
            return linea.AppendLine(lineasAsterisco).ToString(); //Devolvemos la linea con asteriscos
        }

        //Realizamos el mismo procedimiento para dibujar una lineas con el signo igual
        public string lineasIgual()
        {
            string lineasIgual = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxCar; i++)
            {
                lineasIgual += "=";//Agregara un igual hasta llegar la numero maximo de caracteres.
            }
            return linea.AppendLine(lineasIgual).ToString(); //Devolvemos la lienas con iguales
        }

        //Creamos un metodo para poner el texto a la izquierda
        public void TextoIzquierda(string texto)
        {
            //Si la longitud del texto es mayor al numero maximo de caracteres permitidos, realizar el siguiente procedimiento.
            if (texto.Length > maxCar)
            {
                int caracterActual = 0;//Nos indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajar el texto a la siguiente linea
                for (int longitudTexto = texto.Length; longitudTexto > maxCar; longitudTexto -= maxCar)
                {
                    //Agregamos los fragmentos que salgan del texto
                    linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, maxCar));
                    caracterActual += maxCar;
                }
                //agregamos el fragmento restante
                linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual));
            }
            else
            {
                //Si no es mayor solo agregarlo.
                linea.AppendLine(texto);
            }
        }

        //Creamos un metodo para poner texto a la derecha.
        public void TextoDerecha(string texto)
        {
            //Si la longitud del texto es mayor al numero maximo de caracteres permitidos, realizar el siguiente procedimiento.
            if (texto.Length > maxCar)
            {
                int caracterActual = 0;//Nos indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajar el texto a la siguiente linea
                for (int longitudTexto = texto.Length; longitudTexto > maxCar; longitudTexto -= maxCar)
                {
                    //Agregamos los fragmentos que salgan del texto
                    linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, maxCar));
                    caracterActual += maxCar;
                }
                //Variable para poner espacios restntes
                string espacios = "";
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < (maxCar - texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual).Length); i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para alinear a la derecha
                }

                //agregamos el fragmento restante, agregamos antes del texto los espacios
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual));
            }
            else
            {
                string espacios = "";
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < (maxCar - texto.Length); i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para alinear a la derecha
                }
                //Si no es mayor solo agregarlo.
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto);
            }
        }

        //Metodo para centrar el texto
        public void TextoCentro(string texto)
        {
            if (texto.Length > maxCar)
            {
                int caracterActual = 0;//Nos indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajar el texto a la siguiente linea
                for (int longitudTexto = texto.Length; longitudTexto > maxCar; longitudTexto -= maxCar)
                {
                    //Agregamos los fragmentos que salgan del texto
                    linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, maxCar));
                    caracterActual += maxCar;
                }
                //Variable para poner espacios restntes
                string espacios = "";
                //sacamos la cantidad de espacios libres y el resultado lo dividimos entre dos
                int centrar = (maxCar - texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual).Length) / 2;
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < centrar; i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para centrar
                }

                //agregamos el fragmento restante, agregamos antes del texto los espacios
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual));
            }
            else
            {
                string espacios = "";
                //sacamos la cantidad de espacios libres y el resultado lo dividimos entre dos
                int centrar = (maxCar - texto.Length) / 2;
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < centrar; i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para centrar
                }

                //agregamos el fragmento restante, agregamos antes del texto los espacios
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto);

            }
        }

        //Metodo para poner texto a los extremos
        public void TextoExtremos(string textoIzquierdo, string textoDerecho)
        {
            //variables que utilizaremos
            string textoIzq, textoDer, textoCompleto = "", espacios = "";

            //Si el texto que va a la izquierda es mayor a 18, cortamos el texto.
            if (textoIzquierdo.Length > 22)
            {
                cortar = textoIzquierdo.Length - 22;
                textoIzq = textoIzquierdo.Remove(22, cortar);
            }
            else
            { textoIzq = textoIzquierdo; }

            textoCompleto = textoIzq;//Agregamos el primer texto.

            if (textoDerecho.Length > 24)//Si es mayor a 20 lo cortamos
            {
                cortar = textoDerecho.Length - 24;
                textoDer = textoDerecho.Remove(24, cortar);
            }
            else
            { textoDer = textoDerecho; }

            //Obtenemos el numero de espacios restantes para poner textoDerecho al final
            int nroEspacios = maxCar - (textoIzq.Length + textoDer.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
            {
                espacios += " ";//agrega los espacios para poner textoDerecho al final
            }
            textoCompleto += espacios + textoDerecho;//Agregamos el segundo texto con los espacios para alinearlo a la derecha.
            linea.AppendLine(textoCompleto);//agregamos la linea al ticket, al objeto en si.
        }

        //Creamos el encabezado para los articulos
        public void EncabezadoVenta()
        {
            //Escribimos los espacios para mostrar el articulo. En total tienen que ser 40 caracteres
            linea.AppendLine("ITEM                          |CANT  |PRECIO    ");
        }

        public void Header(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Image logo = Image.FromFile("C:\\Work\\detacoopltda\\SucursalVirtual\\DetamaticTotem\\Images\\Logo-Minimalista.png");
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(logo, 0, 0, 238, 73);
        }

        //Metodo para agregar los totales d ela venta
        public void AgregarTotales(string texto, decimal total)
        {
            //Variables que usaremos
            string resumen, valor, textoCompleto, espacios = "";

            if (texto.Length > 29)//Si es mayor a 25 lo cortamos
            {
                cortar = texto.Length - 29;
                resumen = texto.Remove(29, cortar);
            }
            else
            { resumen = texto; }

            textoCompleto = resumen;
            valor = total.ToString("#,#.00");//Agregamos el total previo formateo.

            //Obtenemos el numero de espacios restantes para alinearlos a la derecha
            int nroEspacios = maxCar - (resumen.Length + valor.Length);
            //agregamos los espacios
            for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
            {
                espacios += " ";
            }
            textoCompleto += espacios + valor;
            linea.AppendLine(textoCompleto);
        }

        //Metodo para agreagar articulos al ticket de venta
        public void AgregaArticulo(string articulo, decimal cant, decimal precio) //Modificado por Manuel... Antes cant era int
        {
            //Valida que cant precio e importe esten dentro del rango.
            if (cant.ToString().Length <= 7 && precio.ToString().Length <= 11)
            {
                string elemento = "", espacios = "";
                bool bandera = false;//Indicara si es la primera linea que se escribe cuando bajemos a la segunda si el nombre del articulo no entra en la primera linea
                int nroEspacios = 0;

                //Si el nombre o descripcion del articulo es mayor a 20, bajar a la siguiente linea
                if (articulo.Length > 24)
                {
                    //Colocar la cantidad a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (7 - cant.ToString().Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";//Generamos los espacios necesarios para alinear a la derecha
                    }
                    elemento += espacios + cant.ToString();//agregamos la cantidad con los espacios

                    //Colocar el precio a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (11 - precio.ToString().Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";//Genera los espacios
                    }
                    //el operador += indica que agregar mas cadenas a lo que ya existe.
                    elemento += espacios + precio.ToString();//Agregamos el precio a la variable elemento

                    int caracterActual = 0;//Indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajae a la siguiente linea

                    //Por cada 20 caracteres se agregara una linea siguiente
                    for (int longitudTexto = articulo.Length; longitudTexto > 24; longitudTexto -= 24)
                    {
                        if (bandera == false)//si es false o la primera linea en recorrerer, continuar...
                        {
                            //agregamos los primeros 20 caracteres del nombre del articulos, mas lo que ya tiene la variable elemento
                            linea.AppendLine(articulo.Substring(caracterActual, 24) + elemento);
                            bandera = true;//cambiamos su valor a verdadero
                        }
                        else
                            linea.AppendLine(articulo.Substring(caracterActual, 24));//Solo agrega el nombre del articulo

                        caracterActual += 24;//incrementa en 20 el valor de la variable caracterActual
                    }
                    //Agrega el resto del fragmento del  nombre del articulo
                    linea.AppendLine(articulo.Substring(caracterActual, articulo.Length - caracterActual));

                }
                else //Si no es mayor solo agregarlo, sin dar saltos de lineas
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (24 - articulo.Length); i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " "; //Agrega espacios para completar los 20 caracteres
                    }
                    elemento = articulo + espacios;

                    //Colocar la cantidad a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (7 - cant.ToString().Length);// +(20 - elemento.Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";
                    }
                    elemento += espacios + cant.ToString();

                    //Colocar el precio a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (11 - precio.ToString().Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";
                    }
                    elemento += espacios + precio.ToString();

                    linea.AppendLine(elemento);//Agregamos todo el elemento: nombre del articulo, cant, precio, importe.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                linea.AppendLine("Los valores ingresados para esta fila");
                linea.AppendLine("superan las columnas soportdas por éste.");
                throw new Exception("Los valores ingresados para algunas filas del ticket\nsuperan las columnas soportdas por éste.");
            }
        }

        //Metodos para enviar secuencias de escape a la impresora
        //Para cortar el ticket
        public void CortaTicket()
        {
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "m"); //Caracteres de corte. Estos comando varian segun el tipo de impresora
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "d" + "\x00"); //Avanza 9 renglones, Tambien varian
        }

        //Para abrir el cajon
        public void AbreCajon()
        {
            //Estos tambien varian, tienen que ever el manual de la impresora para poner los correctos.
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "p" + "\x00" + "\x0F" + "\x96"); //Caracteres de apertura cajon 0
                                                                       //linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "p" + "\x01" + "\x0F" + "\x96"); //Caracteres de apertura cajon 1
        }

        //Para mandara a imprimir el texto a la impresora que le indiquemos.
        public void ImprimirTicket(string impresora)
        {
            //Este metodo recibe el nombre de la impresora a la cual se mandara a imprimir y el texto que se imprimira.
            //Usaremos un código que nos proporciona Microsoft. https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/322091

            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(impresora, linea.ToString()); //Imprime texto.
                                                                               //linea.Clear();//Al cabar de imprimir limpia la linea de todo el texto agregado.
        }
    }

    //Clase para mandara a imprimir texto plano a la impresora
    public class RawPrinterHelper
    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "Ticket de Venta";//Este es el nombre con el que guarda el archivo en caso de no imprimir a la impresora fisica.
            di.pDataType = "RAW";//de tipo texto plano
                                 //di.pOutputFile = "D:\\ticket.txt";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola manuel, vas bien encaminado. La pagina del manual que muestras, te indica los comandos disponiles para cada configuracion, pero debe de haber una seccion donde te explique cada uno por individual. Normalmente los comandos van acompañados de parametros. Siendo un comando ESC x, x puede ser parte del comando o un parametro. Si es parte del comando este seria "\x1b\x78" y aparte el parametro , imagina fuente serial = 1. Entonces escoger esa fuente quedaria asi : "\x1b\x78\x01".    Si la x es el parametro entonces quedaria asi el comando "\x1b\x01"

Comment: Hola! lo mismo asumí yo, que en alguna parte del manuel debería venir el comando específico para cada una de las fuentes pero lo estuve revisando y no encontré nada, solo eso. Y gracias por el consejo yo creo que mañana vuelvo a intentar e informaré si funcionó.

Comment: Denada, y suerte yo también ando con una epson en estos días xD

Comment: @Alexmaister que impresora epson estás usando? justo ayer me cambiaron a otro modelo y no encuentro los comandos para este modelo... ahora estoy usando la lx-350

Comment: Buenas Manuel, the dejo una url donde encontraras documentación sobre esa impresora http://biblioteca.museo8bits.es/impresoras/EPSON/Service_Manual_Epson_LX-1170.pdf En la pagina 31 del pdf vienen los comandos

Comment: Normalmente estas impresoras utilizan un protocolo llamado ESC/POS. Cuando te sea muy dificil encontraqr documentación , siempre puedes probar con comandos genéricos de ESC/POS. Aunque una busqueda en google  del tipo : " nombre_impresora_manual  typefile:pdf" Apareceran todas las web con un pdf con ese nombre. Te sera muy util para buscar pdf's en internet

Comment: Esta es la busqueda que hice : "epson lx 350 service manual typefile:pdf" aunque tuve que revisar varias web

Comment: No sabes cuanto te lo agradezco muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seguramente tu error este en que al pasar el comando, no lo haces bien , ya que solo una parte esta en hexadecimal (ESC = \x1b), pero la x (que es un tipo de fuente) la pones como x en vez de \x78.

Prueba esto

```
linea.AppendLine("\x1b\x78"); //(ESC x)

ESC = \x1b
x = \x78
```

Comment: si no ves un cambio de fuente con esto, es posible que ya tengas esa fuente configurada asi que prueba con diferentes fuentes, "\x1b\x6b" ....

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por el aporte, de momento ya no tengo manera de probarlo, quizás hasta mañana pero ya informaré si funcionó.

Comment: Muchas gracias! efectivamente eso solucionó el problema.